# Save the Webpage content as document to Document library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a requirement to save the webpage content as document (`PDF/XPS/Image`) to SharePoint Document library on a button click.

Only client side scripts (`Javascript/Jquery`) are allowed to acheive this. 
It should work in IE8 and above. 
Any idea? Please help